# Unable to open DDMS in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, ddms, logfile

I am developing an xamarin cross platform application when I am trying to open DDMS the following error message is displayed as
    An error has occurred see the log file 
    C:\Users\USERNAME.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1433552022\configuration ,when I checked for this problem the solution was to give permissions and run as administrator I did it but still the error message is being generated .[image: The log window is displaying the following as shown in screenshots].[image: log description]

please help me to resolve the problem .Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with text not picture.

Comment: What do you mean by ddms?

Comment: android device monitor